# Importing adjacent modules in Python3

Tags: import, python-3.6, python-import, python-module

Assume the folder structure is

```
src
  -__init__.py
  -A
    -__init__.py
    -lib.py
  -B
    -__init__.py
    -script.py
```

I am in `script.py` trying to import a function `p()` from `A.lib`. The file `script.py` contains

```py
import os
print(os.listdir())
from A.lib import fkt

if __name__ == "__main__":
  fkt()
```

I am calling `os` to show that my current working directory is in `src/` so the module `A` should be in reach. The return from the print statements is

```py
['A', '.vscode', 'B', '__init__.py']
```

Is there a "correct" way to do this? I figure importing the path via `sys` isn't "correct" so I'd like to avoid doing this.

**Note:** I have tried almost every version of `from src.A.lib`, `from .A.lib`, or `from A.lib` and all of these return either that `src` is not a package or that there is no module `A`.

**OS**: I am running on ubuntu 18.04 LTS with python 3.6.9 using vscode with `"cwd"` set to `"${workspaceFolder}"`.